# iMac running Ubuntu 16.04, Unity Dash & Window Border graphical glitch

Tags: unity, graphics, unity-dash, mac, flicker

I'm Ethan and I am new to asking questions on ask Ubuntu normally it's me reading the answers. I have very little knowledge because I am yet to be an adult and I don't know what model Mac I have either.

My friend and I were at school and we found an iMac running MacOSX so I took it so my friend can use it at his home. Because of the age it won't patch anymore and since I am a Linux user I installed Ubuntu 16.04 just installed it was okay except for one thing. When ever I open the Unity Dash the menu on the top the screen freaks out and there is a lot of glitching and I see the current application name that i'm on in big blurry pixel words stretched across the top of the screen and after a bit the screen goes yellow then it crashes and turns off. My father and I think it's the iMacs' drivers.

My processor is an: Intel Core2 Duo CPU P7350 @ 2.00GHz x 2
Graphics: Gallium  0.4 on NVAC
OS type: 64-bit

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep -A3 -Fe '[0300]'
03.00.0 VGA compatible controller [0300]: NVIDIA Corporation C79 [GeForce 9400] [10de:0867] (rev b1)
  Subsystem: Apple Inc. iMac 9,1 [106b:00ad]
  Kernel driver in use: nouveau
  Kernel modules: nvidiafb, nouveau
```

What do I do to fix it? If you can please give me the solution because this is one of the first graphical problems I have had with Ubuntu!

Cheers Ethan

Comment: I'm sorry but can you explain to me how to do that please?

Comment: I've done that now.

Comment: I don't know what exactly causes the issue, likely a bug in the Nouveau graphics driver. Unless you care deeply for open-source drivers you're going to be better off with the proprietary and usually faster graphics driver provided by the graphics chipset manufacturer Nvidia. The easiest way to install it would be [*Additional Drivers*](/a/680831/175814). The most recent Nvidia driver that supports your chipset is the 340.* branch. Could you please try that and report back with the results?

Comment: If you have any issue during the installation, e. g. the graphics glitch affecting the user interface used for the driver installation critically, shoot me a comment.

Comment: I'm sorry if this is a stupid question but is there a way to reset the graphics driver?

Comment: I'm on Additional Drivers, now what do I do?

Comment: By the way I am using the Terminal to open apps not the unity dash because that starts the glitches.

Comment: I'm currently applying the changes you told me to make.

Comment: Thank you so much! The glitches are gone! Thank you! The iMac has no more glitches and the graphics are better! Thanks alot!

Comment: What do you mean by 'Possible duplicate'?

Comment: That's the default explanatory text when another question is suggested as a duplicate to reviewers. In this case I'm quite sure it will be accepted but it may be perceived as arrogant if I just claim it to be so. It's always possible that I missed something or that somebody has an even better idea.

Comment: Oh okay then and is there a way for me to show appreciation to you for helping me out?

Comment: Not really. Once you earned 15 reputation points you can however vote for the linked question and/or the answer linked above if you found them helpful to raise their visibility to other readers with similar issues. Here are 5 to start because your question is well stated and provides sufficient info.

Comment: Okay then, well enjoy the rest of your day!